# CSS transition effect on MegaMenu

Tags: html, css

I need to slow down opening of dropdown menus, I tried several different transition effects but none of them gave proper solution, my idea was to add transition effect in this segment:

```
/* Showing Drop Down on Mouse Hover */


.megamenu li:hover > div {
    display: block;
}
```

any help would be great, you can check menu on this link:

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrinja/y4shqtsh/)

Comment: Transitions don't work with display propertis. I think the best bet is to fade it in with css or js animations.

Comment: There isnt enough code in the question itself to reproduce the issue....and there is far too much code in the linked fiddle to be a short self contained example. You may have a better response if you strip back your code to (just about) the basics, and include in your question

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle with my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use visibility instead of display:

Change

```
.megamenu li:hover > div {
   display:block;
}
```

to

```
.megamenu li:hover > div {
   visibility:visible;
   opacity:1;
   transition-delay:0.2s;
}
```

And change

```
.megamenu .dropdown_1column, 
.megamenu .dropdown_2columns, 
.megamenu .dropdown_2columns1, 
.megamenu .dropdown_3columns, 
.megamenu .dropdown_4columns,
.megamenu .dropdown_5columns,
.megamenu .dropdown_fullwidth {
    margin:0;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:41px;
    left:-1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 }
```

to

```
.megamenu .dropdown_1column, 
.megamenu .dropdown_2columns, 
.megamenu .dropdown_2columns1, 
.megamenu .dropdown_3columns, 
.megamenu .dropdown_4columns,
.megamenu .dropdown_5columns,
.megamenu .dropdown_fullwidth {
    margin:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:41px;
    left:-1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 }
```

Comment: Where's the fiddle @madforstrenght?